# Using an IF statement within a WHERE clause

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-2012, where-clause, between

I want to show all propID live today.

I have DateLive & DateRemoved for each propID on the PC table but some have a NULL DateRemoved (as they are still live).

I need to use an IF (CASE) statement in my WHEREe to do this.

Something like...

*Where it's today, 
AND (IF they don't have a DateRemoved) then datelive < CalendarDate 
OR IF they do have a Date Removed then CalendarDate is Between DateLive and DateRemoved)*

> ```
> SELECT
>
> C.CalendarDate,
> PC.propID
>
> FROM Calendar C
> CROSS join PropertyCounts PC 
>
> Where C.CalendarDate = getdate()
>
> AND
> (CASE
> WHEN PC.DateRemoved <>NULL THEN C.CalendarDate BETWEEN PC.DateLive AND PC.Dateremoved
> WHEN PC.DateRemoved = NULL THEN PC.DateLive < C.CalendarDate  )
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where C.CalendarDate = getdate()
    AND ((PC.DateRemoved is not null AND C.CalendarDate between PC.DateLive AND PC.Dateremoved)
         OR
         (PC.DateRemoved is null AND PC.DateLive < C.CalendarDate)
        )
```

You're already in an IF statement of sorts with the Where clause. You simply need to build the boolean logic that evaluates to TRUE when a particular record should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this on your where clause substituting the case in parenthesis:

... and ((pc.dateremoved IS NOT NULL and c.calendarDate between pc.datelive and pc.dateremoved) or (pc.dateremoved IS NULL and pc.datelive < c.calendardate))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the complexity of a `CASE` expression (or an `IF` statement), just boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`

```
Where C.CalendarDate = getdate()

AND
(
   (PC.DateRemoved IS NOT NULL AND
      C.CalendarDate BETWEEN PC.DateLive AND PC.Dateremoved)
    OR
   (PC.DateRemoved IS NULL AND PC.DateLive < C.CalendarDate)
)
```

You might also need to do some fiddling around to remove the time component from `getdate()`, e.g. your first condition might need to be:

```
Where C.CalendarDate = CONVERT(date,getdate())
```

because `getdate()` returns a `datetime` with both parts populated, not just a plain date with no time component.